# How do I hide of Bubble cursor on EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

If you have an `EditText`, clicking it will show a Bubble Cursor. I show a picture below (using Twitter app as example)...

My question is:

1. What is this called actually (I think it's not Bubble Cursor definitely)?
2. How to disabled it from our `EditText`? (or from our entire Activity/Fragment/App)

[image]

Comment: That is something propsed by android that cannot be change... as what i know off. Until you hide the cursor! `android:cursorVisible="false"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called text select handle.

There is a tricky way to hide it: replace with an 0px transparent drawable in your style.xml.

drawable/zero_px_transparent.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
     <size android:height="0dp" android:width="0dp"/>
 </shape>
```

And modify your style.xml:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
     <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/zero_px_transparent</item>
     <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/zero_px_transparent</item>
     <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/zero_px_transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Nice workaround. It works! Will see if there's other answer before finalize this as the answer.

Comment: @anhtuannd if user clicks on blank space below cursor then user can see PASTE option

Comment: @voidpointer you are right, in this case we have to extend `ActionMode.Callback` and override `onCreateActionMode` with false return, or empty menu, then call `EditText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback`

Comment: @anhtuannd setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback doesn't seem to fix this, but it does fix double-tapping on a word to show the context menu