# How to remove the frame under the bubble in EditText

Tags: android

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLfVU.jpg)
The problem appears only if the layout is added through WindowManager.addView
How to remove it? If this is a suggestion then how to make the text visible?

android:popupBackground didn't help

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966605/how-do-i-hide-of-bubble-cursor-on-edittext/38966716)

Comment: Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966605/how-do-i-hide-of-bubble-cursor-on-edittext/38966716 not working. This removes the bubble. But does not remove this frame.